# why does it keep saying "cannot reference name before supertype constructor has been called"

Tags: java

I am following a video tutorial, I followed everything but it seem I am keeping getting error:

*"cannot reference name before supertype constructor has been called"*, when using "super"

iteam.java

```
public class iteam {
    String name;

    public iteam(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void use(){
       System.out.println(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Hammer.java

```
package iteams;

/**
 *
 * @author Ayman
 */
public class Hammer extends iteam{

    public Hammer() {
        super(name:"ABC Hammer");
    }
```

main.java

```
package main;
import iteams.Hammer;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Ayman
 */
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Hammer hammer = new Hammer();
        hammer.use();

    }
```

The expectedd result should be: ABCHammer

But it keeps giving me above error.
I am still learning if any one can point me out what I am doing wrong would be good.

however if I use this code in main.java, it works:

```
Hammer hammer = new Hammer("ABC Hammer");
hammer.use();
```

and below in hammer.java

```
public Hammer(String name) {
    super(name);
}
```

Comment: `super(name:"ABC Hammer");` is not proper java, should be `super("ABC Hammer");`

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn using a book, or the official Java tutorials, rather than video tutorials. What you've seen on the screen is not the actual code, but the code embellished by hints added by the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA most probably), that displays the name of the argument next to its value.

Comment: Also learn about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, always. They never start lowercase in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
super(name:"ABC Hammer");
```

Java isn't python-like. There are no named parameters in Java. Your above code isn't valid java syntax.

Thing is: when learning a new language, don't blindly try to apply *concepts from other languages* in your new language. Yes, know your concepts. But then research how/if they are supported in that new language.

Don't invent your own syntax.